# \hbox{} or ~ when beginning a paragraph?

Tags: spacing

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\bigskip
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

This renders as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the `\bigskip` fails to leave a vertical space. This is a common nuisance, which I normally deal with by preceding the command with either `\hbox{}`, or `~`. For instance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\hbox{}\bigskip
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

renders:

[image]

What I want to know is (1) why does this happens, (2) why do `\hbox{}` and `~` work here, and (3) what is the best practice around this issue. (I imagine this has to do with vmode and hmode, but I don't really know what's going on.)

Comment: Vertical space is ignored at page breaks (and there is a break also when the first page starts, by convention); neither method is good: `\hspace*{\bigskipamount}` is the correct one.

Comment: Why aren't these methods good?

Comment: because `~` produces a paragraph with a full white line of text then the bigskip, so you get `\baselineskip` more vertical space and potentially get a page break between the white paragraph and the skip so would still lose the skip but have an anomalous white line at the top of the page. The vertical spacing with `~` is just as if you used `X` (with `\hbox` it's more complicated, but still bad)

Comment: Of course it's `\vspace*`, not `\hspace*` in my previous comment. Fixing David's typos introduced some noise. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you normally don't want spaces at line or page breaks to be preserved and the best practice is `\vspace*` if you really want the space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\bigskipamount}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `~\bigskip This is a test.` doesn't work. You would need an additional par. `\hbox` is a tex primitive and not a latex command. Beside this in both case a page break before the `\bigskip` is possible and then you would again loose the space.

Comment: In an answer to the question backreferenced to this one, Werner suggested using `\mbox{}`. Is this also unadvisable?

Comment: `\mbox{}` is like `~`.